# calling method gives an error of non-static method

Tags: java

I have a method name MakeKK

```
public void MakeKK(String K1, String K2){
    ....
 }
```

I try to call this method in this following way,

```
File f = null;

MakeKK(f.getAbsolutePath()+ "\\Text.txt", f.getAbsolutePath()+"\\Text2.txt");
```

But it gives an error of

```
Error: non-static method MakeKK
```

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: `Makekk` is not a `static` method.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, what else ?

Comment: I suspect you're calling it *from* a static method. I also suspect that's not the complete error message. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list and look at the numerous related questions to the right.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `MakeKK` from `main()`, you have 3 options

```
1. Make MakeKK static..
2. Create an instance of class containing MakeKK and use the instance to call MakeKK.
3. You will get NullPointerException when you run your code as f is null..
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of the class that "contains" the `MakeKK()` method.

```
File f = null;
// ... Here you may add some code to avoid NullPointerException
NameOfClass obj = new NameOfClass(...);
obj.MakeKK(...);
```

so you use it to call that method.

Another solution would be making the method `static`:

```
public static void MakeKK(String K1, String K2){
    ....
}
```

Choosing the correct way depends on what you are doing in the program, and what your method `MakeKK()` does. You could read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods) in order to understand when to use `static` methods.

**Notes:**

- You are initializing `File f` with `null`, which would lead into a `NullPointerException` when you call the method `MakeKK(...)`
- I would recommend you to follow Java naming conventions. You should call your method something like: `nameOfMethod` instead of `NameOfMethod`. This last is used when naming classes, interfaces... Your method *should* be called `makeKK()`.